# Scala : How to define a custom groupBy for a class (just like Ordering)

Tags: scala

I have this

```
case class Box(id: Long, version: String)
object Box {
  implicit def ordering[A <: Box]: Ordering[A] = Ordering.by(_.version)
}
val list1 = List(new Box(0, "A"), new Box(1, "B"), new Box(0, "C"), new Box(2, "D"), new Box(1, "E"))
val list2 = List(new Box(0, "W"), new Box(4, "X"), new Box(0, "Y"), new Box(3, "F"))

trait Aggregator[U] {
   def combOp(l: ListBuffer[U], r: ListBuffer[U]): ListBuffer[U]
}
```

I have something like below, that groupsBy id and then in each group, sorts by version and picks the latest

```
 class GroupByAndTakeLatestAggregator extends Aggregator[Box] {
    override def combOp(l1: ListBuffer[Box], l2: ListBuffer[Box]) = {
       ListBuffer((l1 ++= l2).groupBy(_.id).values.map(_.sorted.reverse.head)).flatten
    }
 }
```

My question is how can I write a generic version of GroupByAndTakeLatestAggregator, that knows how to groupBy and then how to sortBy in each group, assuming that the class defines an implicit ordering and can be grouped on a field.

Basically what I am looking for is a way to specify generic groupBy trait/class just like "Ordering".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `groupBy` operation works on iterables parameterized by some type `A`, and requires a function `A => B` for some `B` on which `==` is defined in a meaningful way. Thus, all we need is to provide an implicit `A => B` function. However, using the extremely general type `A => B` would unnecessary pollute the space of implicits. Therefore, it is better to define a trait `Grouping[A, B]`, which is essentially just a trivial sub-trait of `A => B`. Then we can simply provide the implicit groupings in the companion object of the `Box` class, and also parameterize the GBATLA-thing by the required `Grouping[A, B]` and `Ordering[A]`. Here is an example:

```
/** Essentially a function that groups instances of 
  * type `I` by some feature `F`
  */
trait Grouping[I, F] extends (I => F)
object Grouping {
  def by[I, F](f: I => F) = new Grouping[I, F] {
    def apply(i: I) = f(i)
  }
}

case class Box(id: Long, version: String)
object Box {
  implicit def ordering[A <: Box]: Ordering[A] = Ordering.by(_.version)
  implicit def grouping[A <: Box]: Grouping[A, Long] = Grouping.by(_.id)
}
val list1 = List(new Box(0, "A"), new Box(1, "B"), new Box(0, "C"), new Box(2, "D"), new Box(1, "E"))
val list2 = List(new Box(0, "W"), new Box(4, "X"), new Box(0, "Y"), new Box(3, "F"))

trait Aggregator[U] {
   def combOp(l: List[U], r: List[U]): List[U]
}

class GroupingAndTakeLatestAggregator[B, F](
  grp: Grouping[B, F],
  ord: Ordering[B]
) extends Aggregator[B] {
   override def combOp(l1: List[B], l2: List[B]) = {
    // tried to understand what it did, rewrote it a bit...
    for (vs <- (l1 ++ l2).groupBy(grp).values.toList) 
    yield vs.sorted(ord).reverse.head
  }
}

// Not sure whether you want it. Implicits can quickly pollute everything.
implicit def groupableAndOrderedIsAggregatable[B, F]
  (implicit grp: Grouping[B, F], ord: Ordering[B]): Aggregator[B] = 
  new GroupingAndTakeLatestAggregator(grp, ord)

// Little test, just to see whether an 
// aggregator is constructed automatically
// on-demand
def aggregate[A]
  (as: List[A], bs: List[A])
  (implicit aggr: Aggregator[A]): List[A] = aggr.combOp(as, bs)

println(aggregate(list1, list2))
```